# Populate treeview from database (two classes)

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I found many threads with this theme but all are about situation where populating treeview and communication with database is in one class... I wanted to separate these and i have one class with my form where i want to populate treeview with data that i get from other class. That other class's "job" is only to communicate with database and pass data where it is needed...
Here is my class with form:

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //  on Form load
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<String> lista = DB.DatabaseBroker.GetSports();
        PopulateTreeView(lista);
    }

    private void PopulateTreeView(List<string> lista)
    {
        treeViewSports.Nodes.Clear();

        foreach (string s in lista)
        {
            treeViewSports.Nodes.Add(s);
        }
    }
```

...and here is class where i get data from:

```
static SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MLAD3N-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DBSports;Integrated Security=True");

    public static List<String> GetSports()
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        List<String> sports = new List<String>();

        SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM TableSport", conn);
        SDA.Fill(dataTable);

        if (dataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach(DataRow drow in dataTable.Rows)
            {
                sports.Add(drow[1].ToString());
            }
        }
        return sports;
    }
```

with this i get treeview with sport that looks like this:
[image]

The thing is, i want to add leagues to this treeview so under football i have child nodes with football's leagues.
In my database, leagues table contain foreign keys from sport table, so if my sport football have sportID=1, all leagues in LeagueTable that corresponds with football have foreign key sportID=1.

My question is, how can i get needed leagues from database and place them under football node?

Comment: Anyone? :-/ can't solve this one

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use some kind of tree-structure as a return value for GetSports() instead of "List" and fill this structure with leagues or something else with more complicated sql-query.
Then just fill treeview using data from this structure.